# Explain the following jQuery: $('h1').append($('h1 + h2'));

Tags: jquery

This is a question on one of my test exams.

I've run the code in jsfiddle and what seems to happen is h2 increases dramatically in font size. So it appears h2 is inheriting h1's properties plus its own, but the h1 is unaffected, so I'm not sure.

What is the best way to articulate what is occuring?

```
$('h1').append($('h1 + h2'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/895626/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **appended** an element inside an H1 element. The expected result will be:

```
<h1>
heading1
<h2 id='dude'>
subheading2
</h2>
</h1>
```

Instead of what you had:

```
<h1>
heading1
</h1>

<h2 id='dude'>
subheading2
</h2>
```

Comment: Ahh I see, so why does h2 become larger than h1? Because it's taking it's current font-size plus h1s?

Comment: @AriVictor I think so

Comment: @AriVictor Oh, lol I just found out. h1's default font size is 1.5em, and h2's is 2em. And since em multiplies the parent's font size: It is taking current font size and parent's font size togheter.

Comment: default font size for h1 is (usually) 2em and h2 is 1.5em. But yes, em size is relative to parent so h2 is (2x16) x 1.5 = 48px.